# How to add a text file lines to an array with particular pattern using Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

i have a file.txt which contains

```
##---A1---
a1.la
a2.la
a3.la
##---B1--
b1.la
b3.la
##---C1--
c1.la
c2.la
c3.la
c4.la
```

i want to write a Groovy script so that Array value will be updated a follows

```
Main = [A1 B1 C1]
A1 = [a1.la b1.la c1.la]
B1 = [b1.la b3.la]
C1 = [c1.la c2.la c3.la c4.la]
```

EDIT: need to implement this in Jenkinsfile

Comment: i have to implement this is JENKINS

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it with vanilla Groovy

```
def result = new File('file.txt').text.readLines().inject([result: [:].withDefault { k -> [] }, current: null]) { acc, line ->
    if (line.startsWith('##---')) {
        def token = line.replaceAll('[#-]', '')
        acc.result['Main'] << token
        [result: acc.result, current: token]
    } else if (acc.current) {
        acc.result[acc.current] << line
        acc
    }
}.result
```

Then `result` is a map

```
[
   Main:[A1, B1, C1],
   A1:[a1.la, a2.la, a3.la],
   B1:[b1.la, b3.la],
   C1:[c1.la, c2.la, c3.la, c4.la]
]
```

Not sure if the above is allowed in Jenkins though

Answer (score 0):

With this approach, you capture the whole content in one regular expression and aggregate result afterwards

```groovy
    import java.util.regex.Matcher

    String test = """\
    ##---A1---
    a1.la
    a2.la
    a3.la
    ##---B1--
    b1.la
    b3.la
    ##---C1--
    c1.la
    c2.la
    c3.la
    c4.la
    """
    Matcher matcher = test =~/(?ms)##---(..)-+\n((?:[^#]+?\n)+)/
    Map result = ['Main' : matcher.collect { all, name, list -> name }]
    matcher.each { all, name, list ->
        result[name] = list.readLines()
    }
```

printing the result via `result.each { println it }` results in:

```
Main=[A1, B1, C1]
A1=[a1.la, a2.la, a3.la]
B1=[b1.la, b3.la]
C1=[c1.la, c2.la, c3.la, c4.la]
```

Comment: facing an error here: 
```Script1.groovy: 15: unable to resolve class Matcher 
 @ line 15, column 13.
       Matcher matcher = test =~/(?ms)##---(..)-+\n((?:[^#]+?\n)+)/```

Comment: I added the missing import

Comment: is it possible to print output like. 
```return Main ``` 
[A1, B1, C1]
```return B1``` 
[b1.la, b2.la]

Comment: you can present the result of the collected Map using `key` and `value`:

`result.each { key, value -> println "return $key $value" }`